# Set data breakpoints in GDB for a Fortran executable?

Tags: fortran, gdb, breakpoints, intel-fortran

Is it possible to set data breakpoints in GDB to monitor changes of a global variable in a **Fortran** executable?

### Motivation

I am trying to find out, where an unexpected change to a global configuration variable comes from. Source-code based solutions haven't brought up, where any assignment may happen, so I am trying to use GDB. But while I can easily set up break points for subroutine invocations with readline-completion, and then print global and local variables that are in scope, I can't figure out how to set breakpoints for data changes.

I was unable to set data break points for an executable produced with both GFortran and Intel Fortran. It also doesn't help that [the Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-using-breakpoints-in-the-debugger#WORKING_WITH_DATA_BREAKPOINTS) for data break points only covers Windows.

### Example

For testing purposes I use the following setup:

```
! persons.f90
module mperson
  implicit none

  type :: person
     integer :: age = 0
     character(16) :: name
  end type person

  type(person), allocatable :: persons(:)

contains

  subroutine init_persons(ages, names)
    integer, intent(in) :: ages(:)
    character(*), intent(in) :: names(:)
    integer iPerson

    allocate(persons(size(ages)))
    do iPerson = 1, size(ages)
      persons(iPerson) = person(ages(iPerson), names(iPerson))
    end do
  end subroutine init_persons

  subroutine print_persons()
    integer iPerson
    print '("-------- print_persons --------")'
    do iPerson = 1, size(persons)
      print *, persons(iPerson)
    end do
    persons(2) = person(-1, "undefined")   ! <-- This I would like to catch.
  end subroutine print_persons

end module mperson

program main
  use mperson
  implicit none

  call init_persons([18,42,13], [character(16)::'Alex', 'Max', 'Bobby Tables'])
  call print_persons()
  call print_persons()
contains

end program main
```

Debugged with:

```
(bash) ifort -g -traceback persons.f90 -o persons.bin
(bash) gdb persons.bin
(gdb) break persons.f90:main
(gdb) run
```

Comment: There is no way to tell what "I was unable to set data break points ..." means. Please show the commands you tried and the result of these commands.

Comment: I can't really. I was taking some guesses based on vaguely related documentation or email threads (such as `watch mperson::persons` or `watch __mperson_MOD_persons`) but it didn't do anything meanignful enough to even write about.

Comment: I used `step` to go through the program. Typing `watch persons` just after the `allocate(persons(size(ages)))` statement has been executed works for me. I then get notifications whenever it's modified. This is with gfortran; I don't have Intel's fortran.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick With the executable compiled with `ifort`, trying to do so gives me `Warning: Could not insert hardware break point 2.` after which the debugger aborts the run. With the executable from `gfortran` it works as you desribed, though curiously the debugger stops upon the assignment in `print_persons` *twice*, the first time with the `name` field being incompletely overwritten.

Comment: OK. If gdb aborts the run, it sounds like a bug in gdb. If you can, try a recent version of gdb (source code at https://sourceware.org/pub/gdb/releases/). If gdb still fails, please [file a bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=gdb).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick With gdb 9.1 it works as described. Though it remains a usability issue, that I cannot track the variable, but only the specific allocated instance.